# C# IComparer custom sort list using child count with different condition

Tags: c#, list, sorting, compare

I want to sort C# list using custom comparer.
I have list of TreeNodes and I want to sort them using count of child nodes
(TreeNode.GetNodeCount(true)), but nodes with <=2 node count should be put at end.
Using code below, it sometimes works, but sometimes I get exception that comparer is wrong because comparer output is wrong.

My current code is:

```
public class XPathComparer : IComparer<TreeNode>
{
    public int Compare(TreeNode x, TreeNode y)
    {
        if ( 
            (x != null && x.GetNodeCount(true) <= 2) || 
            (y != null && y.GetNodeCount(true) <= 2) 
            )
            return -1;
        return x.GetNodeCount(true).CompareTo(y.GetNodeCount(true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you haven't provided either the call stack or the exception, I suspect that you get the `Arg_BogusIComparer` `ArgumentException`:

```
<data name="Arg_BogusIComparer" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Unable to sort because the IComparer.Compare() method returns inconsistent results. Either a value does not compare equal to itself, or one value repeatedly compared to another value yields different results. IComparer: '{0}'.</value>
</data>
```

This exception is thrown when your comparer does not provide consistent result for an element. In your example, `x` is less than `y` and `y` is less than `x` at the same time if they both have 1 child.